# passing a pointer address vs pointer to a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm slightly confused between these two pieces of code:

version 1: (gives warnings after compiling)

```
int func(int *ptr2)
{
    *ptr2 += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int *ptr = &a;

    printf("Address of a: %x\n", a);
    printf("Before: %x\n", ptr);
    func(&ptr);
    printf("After: %x\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of a: 5770a18c
Before: 5770a18c                                                                                                           
After: 5770a18d
```

version 2:

```
int func(int **ptr2)
{
    *ptr2 += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int *ptr = &a;

    printf("address of a: %x\n", &a);
    printf("Before: %x\n", ptr);
    func(&ptr);
    printf("After: %x\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of a: cc29385c
Before: cc29385c                                                                                                           
After: cc293860
```

If I'm understanding pointers in C correctly when we pass by reference, we are creating a pointer to that location. This allows us to change the value at the address held by the pointer through the dereference operator.

However, if we want to change the value held by a pointer, we use a pointer to a pointer. We pass the address of the pointer and create a new pointer to hold said address. If we want to change the value, we use the dereference operator to access our pointer's (defined elsewhere) value.

Hopefully I'm on the right track, but I'm struggling to visualize what's happening with version 1 specifically. Mainly, I'd just like to understand the difference in make-up and output between these two programs. I assume version 1 is still a pointer to a pointer, but why are the incremented values different between both programs? If version 1 is successfully incrementing ptr's value (which I suspect is not), why is that I cannot find code with the same syntax? I think I'm missing something fairly trivial here... Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" in C and in your first example you __pass__ a `int**` but __use__ it as if it were a `int*` in the function.

Comment: In both cases `func` increments the value pointed to by `ptr2`, and in both cases that's the value of the pointer `ptr`. The 1st case would also normally issue a warning about passing an `int**` to a function expecting an `int*`, which you shouldn't ignore. Finally, `%x` is not the right format specifier for a pointer, so the `printf` technically invokes UB (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your output, you appear to be compiling for a 32-bit system where addresses and `int` are of that size.

When you increment the value at `*ptr` with that type being `int`, it will simply add 1.

When `*ptr` resolves to an `int*` then it will increment by `sizeof(int)` because the value at the current address in this case is 4 bytes long, so we have to increase the address by the number of bytes that an `int` consumes so that we're pointing at the next int. **Note that doing this is only valid if you actually have allocated memory at the subsequent address.**

Generally you pass a `T**` when the callee needs to modify the address to point to - such as say, the callee performs a `malloc()` to allocate space for the pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the response, these answers are great and have cleared up my main concern. I notice that if I also pass a pointer to 'a' to func(), I can now set *ptr2 = 'a' giving ptr the address location of a in the caller. I'm guessing it's ok to use version 1 if I'm modifying the pointer value with a supplied address? Could you expand why we pass ptr*** vs ptr* when the callee performs memory allocation? Does it have to do with setting the data? I might have to do some refreshing/further reading.

Comment: arguments in C are always passed by value - if I pass an `int` then the function receives a copy of the value. If I pass an `int*` it receives a copy of the address.

Answer (score 0):

`&ptr` is a pointer to a pointer, but what is passed to `func()` is a pointer to `int` converted from `&ptr` in implementation-defined manner. Then, `*ptr2 += 1;` is incrementing `int` and add 1 to what is pointed by `ptr2` (the pointer `ptr` in `main()`, which eventually have the same reepresentation as `int in your system).

In version 2, the pointer to a pointer is correctly passed to `func()`. Therefore, pointer aritimetic is performed and the size of `int` is added to the address.

Note that you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. The correct way to print pointers is like this:

```
printf("Before: %p\n", (void*)ptr);
```

As you see, cast the pointer to `void*` and use `%p` specifier.